# Http requests redirected to https

Tags: apache, jboss, httpd.conf

Goal: I want all requests made to http://mydomain to be redirected to https://mydomain.

Today I have an Apache web server which handles all incoming requests made to http://mydomain and redirects them to http://localhost:8080 (JBoss application server). I'm using proxypass for my virtual host in the Apache configuration.

What do I need to do to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

The Apache Foundation [recommended approach](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect) is to have a dummy `VirtualHost` on port 80 with:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/"
</VirtualHost>
```

You can configure your existing `VirtualHost` for SSL.